# Is there a report to export the transfers from CiviCRM to my bank account?

Tags: civireport

I can see all of the payments that people make, but I would also like a CSV export that includes the transfers from civiCRM to my bank account.  Is there a report for that?

Answer (score 2):

Amy, Welcome to SE world.

You can use contribution report or contribution search to list all the contribution recorded in CiviCRM based on Payment method used in one of your payment processor. For example if you are using PayPal and have payment method set to Credit card for the paypal payment processor then you can search on payment method in 'Credit card' and then export the results in a csv.

To get the list of payments associated with the contribution(s) you can use [Find Payments](https://civicrm.org/extensions/find-payments) extension to find the payments for payment method in 'Credit Card' and  then export the result into CSV.

HTH

Pradeep